# Generating Labels from resource file in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resources

How to generate labels,textblocks,listview items from resource file as in .Net framework in ruby on rails 3.This gives advantage of customizing view of webpage for different users and locale.I want to create many resource files and use it for generating views.I wish to know how to do this?

Comment: For those who never used .Net, can you explain what exactly you need?

Comment: for example suppose I am displaying 5 results per page.Then somehow I wish to show 8 results per page,then I have to change the code.Instead,if I have the @NumOfResults in external resource file,it will be very easy.Also,I would like to store images so that I don't have to update path if I ever supposed to change directory structure

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is Rail's Internationalization (or l18n).   You can find the most current reference and examples of how to do this in the Rails Guides, under [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Additional information can be found on the [Rails I18n Wiki](http://ruby-i18n.org/wiki).